# Problems with "referencing lengths max_bars_back" error

Tags: pine-script

I'm currently working on a new script but encounter some strange behaviour depending on what stock or index I'm currently working on.
My new script seems to work totally fine on some stocks but throws the following error on other stocks, indexes or ForEx pairs:

> Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series. Try using max_bars_back in the study or strategy function

I already read the entry in the Pine documentation and I also tried adding "max_bars_back" to the study without any results.

So I broke my script down for demonstration purposes and now have a version that will throw this error on every stock.

Here is the code:

```
//@version=4
study("StackOverflow_Test", overlay = true, max_bars_back=100)

var int loopRange = 0                  
var int trendState = 2                  

var bool firstBreak = true

var float hp_last = low                   
var float hp_current = high               

float tempHighest = 0                   
int tempHighPosition = 0                

var bool waitForConfirmation = false

float source = close              // Used Price

for i = loopRange to 0
    if ( source[i] > tempHighest )
        tempHighest := source[i]
        tempHighPosition := i

if ( source > hp_current )          
    waitForConfirmation := true     
    hp_current := source            

if ( waitForConfirmation )                  
    if ( firstBreak )                   
        firstBreak := false             
        if ( trendState == 1 )          
            trendState := 2
        else                            
            trendState := 0
        hp_last := hp_current[1]           
    
    if ( tempHighPosition > 3 )       
        loopRange := 3                
        waitForConfirmation := false                    
        firstBreak := true                              

loopRange := loopRange + 1                  

color trendLineColor = color.green
if ( trendState == 0 )
    trendLineColor := color.green
else if ( trendState == 1 )
    trendLineColor := color.red
else
    trendLineColor := color.silver

// Plot trendline
plot(source, color = trendLineColor)
```

If I remove the first for-loop or the lines:

```
if ( trendState == 1 )          
    trendState := 2
else                            
    trendState := 0
```

The error won't occur.

I thought the error means that I try to access data out of bounds but I fail to see where exactly...
Does anyone of you have an idea what line causes this behaviour?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with an explanation of what you're trying to achieve? I think that'll enable the community to help you. Also, I think you're approaching your problem the wrong way by using for loops.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
I put more information below as a comment under Andrey's answer.
But I maybe add here why I'm using the for-loop. 
I want to search for new high points and will use them as value areas and an estimateion if the market is in a range or in an uptrend. I don't use the Highest/Lowest methods because I don't want a "breakout" for every new candle in an uptrend. I only want the new high point at the end of the uptrend so when a certain amount of canldes closes below the new high point to the left and right. For this reason I use the loop to get not only the high point

Comment: value but also it's position in the loopRange.
The loopRange is always the last high point to the new high point and will get updated after the new high point is confirmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for i = loopRange to 0
    if ( source[i] > tempHighest )
        tempHighest := source[i]
        tempHighPosition := i
...              
loopRange := loopRange + 1
```

you go through all available history on every bar for find Highest High. This is inefficient and give you the error "referencing length of a series". If you describe final goal of your script we can offer more efficient workaround.

Comment: Hi Born and Andrey,
I want to locate the highest and lowest value in a given range that gets adjusted regularily (~10-50 Candles most of the time)
I know that I could use the Highest/Lowest method but I want a solution that won't utilize those methods.
I don't understand why this loop yields a problem, I start with a looprange of 0 (so only 1 iteration) and than only positive values that never exceeds the historical candles.
I even added "max_bars_back=100" to the study to avoid problems. And the strangest thing is, that my original script works on certain stocks but yields the error

Comment: on other stocks. 
So if the loop would access more than the historical candles it should not work on all stocks and not only fail on Index or forex pairs....
When I increment the loopRange starting from 0 there should be no way that I access data out of bounds or am I overlooking something?
As you can see I adjust the looping range after 3 lower candles are formed after the last high. So my reference should be never higher than ~50 candles in the past and always start from the first candle of the last high

Comment: I can post my whole script here but last time I did something similiar, people complained that the code is to long and that I should isolate and break down the code so that one can see the problem more easily.

Comment: Update: I just tried adding
if ( loopRange > bar_index)
    loopRange := bar_index
To make sure that it is impossible to reference data further back than the very first historical candle but it still throws this error...

Comment: `So my reference should be never higher than ~50 candles` - if so, you can fix the problem such way: `loopRange := min(loopRange + 1, 50)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to fix the problem :), I added loopRange := min(loopRange + 1, 150) at the end of the script. But last question: I thought the max_bar_index in the study fullfills exactly this purpose doesn't it?

Comment: `max_bars_back = 150` says engine that history max length for all series (with history) variables and objects have maximum 150 history values. If you doesn't specify `max_bars_back` value, the engine try to detect maximum history length for each series variable individually on first 200-300 bars. If you reference more history after 1000th bar the “referencing lengths max_bars_back” error occur.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loop you can try the following code

**solution 1:**

```
tempHighest = highest(source, loopRange)
tempHighPosition = highestbars(source, loopRange)
```

However, these builtin functions may loop too. The following code will not loop

**solution 2:**

```
var tempHighest = 0.0
var tempHighPosition = 0

if (source > tempHighest)
    tempHighest := source
    tempHighPosition := 0
else
    tempHighPosition := tempHighPosition + 1
```